# Firebase web vs ios and android version for react native project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm new to app development and this has been confusing me.

I have a project created in react-native that I want to be available for both android and iOS.
I've watched a few tutorials on how to create a firebase database for the backend for react native and some of them select the 'Web' version while building the app.

So am I correct in assuming that I just need to select the 'Web' version and my app would still work for both iOS and android? (I don't need to select the android AND the iOS versions as well)

Thanks for the help!

[image: Firebase app versions]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends...

If you use the regular [JavaScript SDK (for Web)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) for Firebase in your React Native app, you don't need to create any application descriptor in your Firebase project. But in that case you'll only have access to the functionality of Firebase that is available in that JavaScript SDK.

The more common approach is to use the [React Native Firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/) libraries that wrap the native SDKs for iOS and Android. Since these wrap the native SDKs, you will need to create a description for each of those in your Firebase project.