# React Native Firebase type android or Web App?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo, redux-firestore

I want to turn my reactjs web app in to android app via google play store. The backend is in firebase! which type of setup should i choose web or android ?
I want both web app and android sharing the same data!

the links bellow makes my confusion more clear!

[add app]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1hqk.jpg

[type of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7khES.jpg)

Comment: Well, an Android app should be type android app :)

Comment: I think this question answers it more clearly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69096755/209288 You can define just a "web" Firebase app for a React Native app which will work for both the Android and iOS generated apps - but only if you use all web oriented JS SDKs in your React Native code. I have done this and it worked fine, until I wanted to use one of the components from Invertase which required an Android app, and I had the same confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of want you're trying to achieve here.

If your ReactJS App is a PWA, you can convert it to a [TWA](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/trusted-web-activity/) to publish it to the Play Store. In that case no need to "add" a new app to your firebase project.

If you're building an Android App and you want to share the data, then you'll need to "add" a new app in your Firebase project, for Android and you'll be able to connect to the same firestore DB, Realtime DB, Cloud Storage etc from both your app and your website. More Details to add the firebase SDK to your Android App [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

If you haven't build anything yet, perhaps start by the ReactJS app, and therefor creating a web app on your Firebase project.
And if you're trying to build a React Native App, read the [RN Firebase SDK Documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/). It is written that you'll have to create an Android app on your Firebase project, and an iOS app.

Comment: This is true only IF you are using that rnfirebase.io wrapper package, which is just an option. If you use Google's Firebase JS SDKs directly then you can use the Web Firebase app.